"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.distutils'" while installing lap
PS C:\Users\korku\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1> pip install lap
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting lap
  Using cached lap-0.4.0.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: lap
  Building wheel for lap (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      C:\Users\korku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mcq007j3\lap_1a667a46721c4696a80d66713cfba425\setup.py:4: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
        from pkg_resources import parse_version
      Partial import of lap during the build process.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\korku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mcq007j3\lap_1a667a46721c4696a80d66713cfba425\setup.py", line 236, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "C:\Users\korku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mcq007j3\lap_1a667a46721c4696a80d66713cfba425\setup.py", line 223, in setup_package
          from numpy.distutils.core import setup
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.distutils'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lap
  Running setup.py clean for lap
Failed to build lap
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (lap)

I've tried:
pip install cmake


numpy.distutils was deprecated some time ago and has been removed for Python >3.12
See here for migration advice
lap 0.4.0 was last released in 2018 and has obviously not been maintained

Update pip first. Then install/update the wheel and setuptools packages. Then try installing the lab module.
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade wheel
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install lab


The standard joke answer to your question title is: This is (supposedly) "the definition of insanity" .
But seriously, this may be another problem caused by the Python leadership passing some new rules (PEP 668) that tries to help operating system companies by forcing ordinary sysadmins to use arcane python specific techniques such as "python virtual environments" .
P.S.
Posting this answer was delayed by the 30 minute rule being applied to my entirely human answer.
